# App has stopped. Не работает приложение

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button_1 = findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

2 Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
Button btnSubmit;
int sum;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
    }
    countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));

    ListView countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

    countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++)
    {
        sum += population[i];
    }

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("average", sum);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

3 Activity

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvView;
int sum;
int defaultValue = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);

    tvView.setText("Avarage =: " + sum);
}
}
```

Вот логи

```
`09-23 12:32:10.647 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/art: Late-enabling - 
 Xcheck:jni
 09-23 12:32:10.648 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 W/art: Unexpected CPU 
 variant for X86 using defaults: x86
 09-23 12:32:11.454 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 W/System: ClassLoader 
 referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/lib/x86
 09-23 12:32:11.478 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/InstantRun: starting 
 instant run server: is main process
 09-23 12:32:12.678 1858-1874/com.example.admin.app_1 E/libEGL: 
 load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library 
 "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
 09-23 12:32:13.500 1858-1874/com.example.admin.app_1 I/OpenGLRenderer: 
 Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 09-23 12:32:23.288 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/Choreographer: 
 Skipped 653 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
 thread.
 09-23 12:32:23.731 1858-1874/com.example.admin.app_1 E/EGL_emulation: tid 
 1874: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
 09-23 12:32:23.735 1858-1874/com.example.admin.app_1 W/OpenGLRenderer: 
 Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xcf2c0cc0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
 09-23 12:32:25.207 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/Choreographer: 
 Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
 thread.
 09-23 12:32:25.792 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/Choreographer: 
 Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
 thread.
 09-23 12:38:30.845 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 W/art: Before Android 
 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 


    android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-23 12:38:35.052 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
09-23 12:38:35.053 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.admin.app_1.Main2Activity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Main2Activity.java:27)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.admin.app_1-1/split_lib_slice_7_ap
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.admin.app_1.Main2Activity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Main2Activity.java:27)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
09-23 12:38:35.674 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 I/System.out: Peru -> 6310000
    Paraguay -> 2300000
    Mexico -> 7000000
    Jamaica -> 500000
    Urugay -> 6770000
09-23 12:38:35.678 1858-1858/com.example.admin.app_1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.app_1, PID: 1858
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.app_1/com.example.admin.app_1.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.admin.app_1.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

activity_main2

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:id="@+id/countriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/btnSubmit">
    </Button>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @TimurVI, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1):

Вот главная строчка которая указывает на ошибку

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.app_1/com.example.admin.app_1.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

У вас ListView - null

```
ListView countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
```

возвращает null

Comment: так в коде все нормально. Как он возвращает null ?

Comment: Значит не всё нормально - у Вас должен быть `ListView` с `id` `countriesList` в `activity_main.xml` (проверьте все, если их несколько). А скорее всего корень проблемы в том, что Вы не тот лэйаут в `Main2Activity` ставите (на `setContentView` обратите внимание).

Comment: меня смущает название id - countriesList - складывается впечатление что это не id ListView. Покажите xml Activity2. Как написал woesss - скорей всего вы сетите не тот лайоут в Активити2

Comment: @Eugene Zaychenko, выложил выше

Comment: Main2Activity и в правду было в сетите activity_main, но после изминения на activity_main2 программа так же не запускается